# What is the difference between deque.at(0) vs deque[0]

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

So i have this queue

```
deque<int> deq1(2,10);
```

I Have accessed the element using 2 way and both of them return the same value

```
cout<<deq1[0];
cout<<deq1.at(0);
```

why did them make a special function to do the same thing or is one way better than the other?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: What does your *text books* tell you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is that the function `at` throw an exception if the index is out of range while the `operator[]` doesn't make any check. You can see the documentation here

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/at

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_at

Comment: I'd like to insist on the fact that throwing an exception is a good thing, not a bad thing, and you should probably prefer `at` to `operator[]`. If you call `operator[]` with a wrong index, it will cause problems, but they will be much harder to track down.

Comment: @Stef If you know that you won't use an index outside the range (e.g. it doesn't depend on any user input, file input, etc...) and you care about performances, using `operator[]()` is wiser than performing an unnecessary check with `at()`. The thing is, there is no better or worse version, each one has its own/proper usages, hence why there are two functions instead of one.

Comment: @Fareanor I actually agree with you, but my concern was that this answer could make it sound like "`at` risks producing an exception, whereas `[]` doesn't have that risk, so `[]` is safer than `at`". Which is the opposite of the truth. Hence my comment. If someone comes to this page because they couldn't understand the difference between `at` and `[]` from the documentation, I'm guessing the difference in performance between `[]` and `at` isn't the most relevant issue to them.

Comment: @Stef My answer was not intended to promote one or another solution. May be you can help me to improve my answer!